# Beacons: Android / Iphone Bluetooth range

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, ibeacon

we try to develop a ios and andorid app with beacons.
it only uses the entry and exit event.

now our problem is that the android gets the enter event at ~7meter
and the iphone ~1.5meter.

the beacon settings are TX Power -23dbm, Measured Power -80.

is there a way to adjust the android or iphone to get the same range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with mobile devices because **each model has a different Bluetooth antenna and chip, some of which pick up signals better than others.**  The problem is particularly noticeable across the wide variety of Android models.

There is no magic fix, but **you can do ranging at the same time as monitoring, and trigger your logic only if you get a ranging result with `beacon.distance < 1.5`.**  This is not a perfect solution, as Android models can sometimes have inaccurate distance estimates due to the same varying antenna gain characteristics.  For select devices. This may be a much better solution.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot.